# Azure Data Share resource is complaining tags should be all in lower case while trying to provision from terraform

Tags: azure, tags, azure-data-share

While provisioning a data share account resource using terraform , the resource creation fails because of the following error : a tag key 'BusinessUnit' expected to be all in lowercase.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

After this I provisioned the resource without tags from terraform, and then went onto Azure Portal to add the tags manually to check the behaviour.

While adding tags from Azure Portal, for the tag key, the Pascal casing is automatically getting changed to CamelCase . eg. Tag key 'BusinessUnit' is getting changed to 'businessUnit' .

Has anyone faced this ? any idea how to work around this ? I have lodged a support ticket with MS for this.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBrV2.png

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. Currently, I'm working with the Azure Product team and I will update you once we hear back from them.

Comment: I encounter the same behavior. My Tag "AzCosts" becomes "azCosts".

Comment: Same issue after 3 years. Any updates?